# Prevent unused fonts files to loaded in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using elementor for WordPress. But when I open inspect menu for any page of website, it is showing almost 18 files are being loaded while I am using single font while is google font. How can I remove or block additional files from loading.

[image]

I tried to write a code in functions.php that will block given file from loading but it did not work.

```
function remove_extra_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style('assets/dist/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
'); // Replace 'font-awesome' with the handle of the font you want to dequeue
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_extra_fonts', 999);
```

Comment: That's not how [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189985/how-to-properly-dequeue-scripts-and-styles-in-child-theme) works. You need to find the handle identifier to dequeue the stylesheet (e.g by checking the functions/parent theme functions.php) or the output html

Comment: And  what if I want to use only local fonts on users site rather than blocking additional fonts files to load.

Comment: wp_dequeue_style is the right way. My point is you didn't call it correctly. Ideally you would replace all extnal styles with locally hosted ones.  See the previous link